# Selector ascendente CSS

Tags: css, css3

Quiero ocultar un elemento hermano con css, si tiene una etiqueta de clase en su interior. He estado haciendo pruebas con `has:`, pero no se como seleccionar el hermano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero ocultar el elemento la clase `p-multiselect-header`, si el elemento con clase `.p-multiselect-items-wrapper` con tiene algún elemento con la clase  `.multiselect-empty-message`.

Sería algo así, pero no me funciona un selector para el elemento hermano.

```
.p-multiselect-header:has(+'.p-multiselect-items-wrapper'):has(>'.multiselect-empty-message') {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: intenta directo identificando con la clase que no queres que se muestre prueba con esto `.p-multiselect-header:has(.p-multiselect-items-wrapper) { display: none; }`

Comment: Pero si te das cuenta es un elemento hermano, no descendente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te va a resultar más facíl se empezas el selector desde el padre de ambos, es decir, desde `.p-multiselect-panel`.

Entonces podemos decir que:

- Si `.p-multiselect-panel` tiene un hijo `.p-multiselect-items-wrapper` que tiene un hijo `.p-multiselect-items` y que tiene un hijo `.p-multiselect-empty-message`, entonces al hijo `.p-multiselect-header` lo ocultamos.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.p-multiselect-panel:has(>.p-multiselect-items-wrapper > .p-multiselect-items > .p-multiselect-empty-message)>.p-multiselect-header {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-multiselect-panel">
  <div class="p-multiselect-header">Header</div>
  <div class="p-multiselect-items-wrapper">
    <ul class="p-multiselect-items">
      <li class="p-multiselect-empty-message">Empty</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PD:** La regla se puede simplificar a `.p-multiselect-panel:has(.p-multiselect-empty-message) > .p-multiselect-header`, pero si existe la posibilidad de tener elemento anidados se prestaria a error.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar el [selector combinado de hermanos `~`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

La sintaxis es:

```
hermano1 ~ hermano2
```

El estilo se aplica sobre los elementos `hermano2` si se que estén después de un elemento `hermano1` que comparta el mismo ancestro directo.

```css
.contenedor:has(> .hijo) ~ .elemento {
    background: red;
}

.hijo, .elemento {
    background: green;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
}

.contenedor {
    display: block;
    paddint: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento"></div>
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
</div>
<div class="elemento"></div>
```

Otra forma que no depende del orden es a través del padre:

```css
.padre:has(.nieto) .elemento {
    background: red;
}

.nieto, .elemento {
    background: green;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="elemento"></div>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="nieto"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="elemento"></div>
</div>
```